# google.cloud.bigquery python. How to get the bytes processed by query

Tags: python-2.7, google-bigquery

I am using Google BigQuery in my python code to fetch and insert data into tables. I would like to know the bytes processed by my queries. Is there a way to do that? I am currently using google.cloud.bigquery in python2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

In version `0.28.0` you can use either `dry_run` or get the results after the job is done, like so:

```
import google.cloud.bigquery as bq
import os

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']='path/to/your/secrets.json'
bc = bq.Client()
job_config = bq.QueryJobConfig()
job_config.dry_run = True

query = """your query"""    
query_job = bc.query(query, job_config)
print "Total bytes this query will process: {}".format(
    query_job.total_bytes_processed)

# this approach is after you run the job without ``dry_run``
import time
query = """your query"""
query_job = bc.query(query)
while(query_job.done() != True):
    time.sleep(1)
print "Total bytes processed: {}".format(
    query_job.total_bytes_processed)
```

Comment: Thank you. I would like to know the bytes processed before actually executing the query. The example above where we use dry_run flag, does this give bytes-processed before executing actual query?

Comment: Exactly. This being the case, you should use `dry_run` indeed. It does not run your query, it just computes the total bytes that will be processed (another important feature that I use is the `maximum_billing_bytes` that puts a threshold on how much bytes it allows to be processed before throwing an exception. Quite important to protect you against mistakes in queries that might query terasbytes of data by mistake).

Comment: Okay. After validating the total_bytes_processed field, and then call bc.result(), it throws 'google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404'. If I call result() with a job instance that created with no job_config, then it works fine. That is I need to use client.query(query, job_config) for getting bytes-processed, then again re-initialise the bc with client.query(query) with no job_config, to run the real query. Is this the right way of doing?

Comment: If you specified the job with `dry_run=True` then indeed you won't have any result to fetch as no real query is run. The problem is not the job_config itself but the property dry_run set to true there. If you set it to `False` it should work normally.

Comment: Thank you so much. That helped a lot.